# C# WebAPI Routing by POST value type

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a request to create a Web API that is able to accept a POST request and take different actions depending on the type of data (DataAvailableNotification vs ExpiredNotification) received in the parameters.

I've created an ApiController and exposed two methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DataAvailable(DataAvailableNotification dataAvailable,
        [FromUri] string book, [FromUri] string riskType)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void DataAvailable(ExpiredNotification dataAvailable,
        [FromUri] string book, [FromUri] string riskType)
    {

    }

public class DataAvailableNotification
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
    public string RdfType { get { return "App.RRSRC.Feeds.DataAvailable"; } }

    public string SnapshotRevisionId { get; set; }

    public string[] URLs { get; set; }

    public string ConsumerId { get; set; }

    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }
}

public class ExpiredNotification
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
    public string RdfType { get { return "Service.Feeds.Expired"; } }

    public string ConsumerId { get; set; }

    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

However, they don't get called at all.

If I comment out one of them the notification reaches the controller but I cannot handle the notification type correctly (given that both notifications will map to the same method).

Is there any way configuring Web API to look into the type of the POSTed value and call the best matching controller method?

PS: I cannot have 2 different of URLs to handle the different notifications. So please don't suggest this.

Comment: What's the difference between `DataAvailableNotification` and `ExpiredNotification`? If you want to have the same url for both, how do you expect the routing engine to know which action to call?

Comment: Further to @DarinDimitrov's comment: what you are trying to do is not how routing works. You need to rethink your approach here, for example having a more complex object that can handle both types.

Comment: Hi @DarinDimitrov. I've updated the post with the class definitions for the DataAvailableNotification and ExpiredNotification.

Comment: Hi @AdrianWragg. Yes. That could be an approach. But I'm hoping that I can just expose the 2 different methods in the controller. This would be a cleaner implementation. And I'm also hoping that WebAPI offers a way of handling this scenario for me :).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I was hoping it can route based on the body in the HTTP POST.

Comment: Yes it can be based on the body of the HTTP. Unfortunately from what I can see the `$type` property is readonly. This means that its value is not part of the HTTP payload. So what you are asking is absolutely impossible because the model binder has no way of knowing which model to instantiate if the caller doesn't tell it somehow.

Comment: Yes. The $type isn't usable in this scenario. I've created a new model binder and it seems that the model binder determines the type of model prior to the call to public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext). Also, even with a new model binder, if I have 2 methods to handle the 2 types of notifications I don't get any call to either handler methods or to the model binder.

Comment: Why don't you create just one POST action (which is the "correct" way if you follow REST) , and based on the value, you call different methods to deal with your data? Doing what you are trying, seems to me much of a overhead. Don't complicate things!

Comment: @jpgrassi This is exactly what I've done for now. But I was hoping there is a way for the Web API framework to determine the right type to deserialize and call the appropriate handler.

Comment: Do you really need the actions to be a POST? I just created a test project and I could make what you want but using GET.

Comment: @jpgrassi The HTTP POST is done by an external component. I can only adhere to its API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I settled with is similar to what @Nikosi and @jpgrassi suggested.

In the controller I've created a single notification point:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Notify(BaseNotification notification, 
        [FromUri] string book, [FromUri] string riskType)
    {
        DataAvailableNotification dataAvailableNotification;
        ExpiredNotification expiredNotification;

        if ((dataAvailableNotification = notification as DataAvailableNotification) != null)
        {
            HandleDataAvailableNotification(dataAvailableNotification);
        }
        else if ((expiredNotification = notification as ExpiredNotification) != null)
        {
            HandleExpiredNotification(expiredNotification);
        }
    }

    private void HandleDataAvailableNotification(DataAvailableNotification dataAvailableNotification)
    {
    }

    private void HandleExpiredNotification(ExpiredNotification expiredNotification)
    {
    }
```

BaseNotification is the base class for all notifications:

```
public abstract class BaseNotification
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
    public abstract string RdfType { get; }

    public string ConsumerId { get; set; }

    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

Created a JsonConverter:

```
public class RdfNotificationJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var resultJson = JObject.Load(reader);
        var rdfType = resultJson["$type"].ToObject<string>();

        BaseNotification result;

        switch (rdfType)
        {
            case "App.RRSRC.Feeds.DataAvailable":
            {
                result = new DataAvailableNotification
                {
                    SnapshotRevisionId = resultJson["SnapshotRevisionId"].ToObject<string>(),
                    URLs = resultJson["URLs"].ToObject<string[]>()
                };
                break;
            }
            case "Service.Feeds.Expired":
            {
                result = new ExpiredNotification();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        result.ChannelId = resultJson["ChannelId"].ToObject<Guid>();
        result.ConsumerId = resultJson["ConsumerId"].ToObject<string>();

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(BaseNotification);
    }
}
```

And registered the new converter in the configuration:

```
    public static void Configure(HttpSelfHostConfiguration config)
    {
        Throw.IfNull(config, "config");

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new RdfNotificationJsonConverter());
     }
```

I like this solution better because I have the actual type in the controller and the converter handles the ugly deserialization part (also more testable).

PS: I'll move the literal strings somewhere else so I don't specify them twice in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use one action and filter based on the type.
I got around the same issue by using reflection and doing something like the following.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void DataAvailable([FromBody]IDictionary<string, string> dataAvailable,
    [FromUri] string book, [FromUri] string riskType) {
    if(dataAvailable != null && dataAvailable.ContainsKey("$type") {
        var type = dataAvaliable["$type"];
        if(type == "App.RRSRC.Feeds.DataAvailable"){
           DataAvailableNotification obj = createInstanceOf<DataAvailableNotification>(dataAvailable);
           DataAvailable(obj,book,riskType);
        } else if (type == "Service.Feeds.Expired") {
           ExpiredNotification obj = createInstanceOf<ExpiredNotification>(dataAvailable);
           DataAvailable(obj,book,riskType);
        }
    }
}

private void DataAvailable(DataAvailableNotification dataAvailable, string book, string riskType) {

}

private void DataAvailable(ExpiredNotification dataAvailable, string book, string riskType) {

}

private T createInstanceOf<T>(IDictionary<string, string> data) where T : class, new() {
    var result = new T();
    var type = typeof(T);
    //map properties
    foreach (var kvp in data) {
        var propertyName = kvp.Key;
        var rawValue = kvp.Value;
        var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property != null && property.CanWrite) {
            property.SetValue(result, rawValue );
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```